# Xcode embedding second project, linking error

Tags: ios, xcode, linker

I have a project that uses (or would like to) the route-me (alpstein fork). I have followed  the installations interaction with some limited success.

I have dragged "MapView.xcodeproj" in to my project, I have added mapview.lib, to "target dependancies" and "link binaries with libraries".

if I go to my MapViewController, i can write all my code and I get no errors when importing RMmapView.h. So the compiler is seeing the imported library, however when i build the application I get this error

```
d /Users/macuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/G4EMA-djubtvaxtspjxbbolnkeaoatnyqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/G4EMA.app/G4EMA normal i386
cd /Users/macuser/Dropbox/G4EMA
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 5.1
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -L/Users/macuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/G4EMA-djubtvaxtspjxbbolnkeaoatnyqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -LRM -LRM/Alpstein-route-me-f06f2d0 -LRM/MapView -LRM/Proj4 -LRM/samples -LRM/Alpstein-route-me-f06f2d0/MapView -LRM/Alpstein-route-me-f06f2d0/Proj4 -LRM/Alpstein-route-me-f06f2d0/samples -LRM/MapView/Map -LRM/MapView/UnitTesting -LRM/samples/LayeredMap -LRM/samples/MapMemoryLeaksCheck -LRM/samples/MapTestbed -LRM/samples/MapTestbedFlipMaps -LRM/samples/MapTestbedTwoMaps -LRM/samples/MarkerMurder -LRM/samples/ProgrammaticMap -LRM/Alpstein-route-me-f06f2d0/MapView/Map -LRM/Alpstein-route-me-f06f2d0/MapView/UnitTesting -LRM/Alpstein-route-me-f06f2d0/samples/LayeredMap -LRM/Alpstein-route-me-f06f2d0/samples/MapMemoryLeaksCheck -LRM/Alpstein-route-me-f06f2d0/samples/MapTestbed -LRM/Alpstein-route-me-f06f2d0/samples/MapTestbedFlipMaps -LRM/Alpstein-route-me-f06f2d0/samples/MapTestbedTwoMaps -LRM/Alpstein-route-me-f06f2d0/samples/MarkerMurder -LRM/Alpstein-route-me-f06f2d0/samples/ProgrammaticMap -LRM/MapView/Map/FMDB -LRM/MapView/Map/Resources -LRM/MapView/Map/SMCalloutView -LRM/samples/LayeredMap/Classes -LRM/samples/MapMemoryLeaksCheck/Classes -LRM/samples/MapTestbed/Classes -LRM/samples/MapTestbedFlipMaps/Classes -LRM/samples/MapTestbedTwoMaps/Classes -LRM/samples/MarkerMurder/Classes -LRM/samples/ProgrammaticMap/Classes -LRM/Alpstein-route-me-f06f2d0/MapView/Map/FMDB -LRM/Alpstein-route-me-f06f2d0/MapView/Map/Resources -LRM/Alpstein-route-me-f06f2d0/MapView/Map/SMCalloutView -LRM/Alpstein-route-me-f06f2d0/samples/LayeredMap/Classes -LRM/Alpstein-route-me-f06f2d0/samples/MapMemoryLeaksCheck/Classes -LRM/Alpstein-route-me-f06f2d0/samples/MapTestbed/Classes -LRM/Alpstein-route-me-f06f2d0/samples/MapTestbedFlipMaps/Classes -LRM/Alpstein-route-me-f06f2d0/samples/MapTestbedTwoMaps/Classes -LRM/Alpstein-route-me-f06f2d0/samples/MarkerMurder/Classes -LRM/Alpstein-route-me-f06f2d0/samples/ProgrammaticMap/Classes -F/Users/macuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/G4EMA-djubtvaxtspjxbbolnkeaoatnyqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/macuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/G4EMA-djubtvaxtspjxbbolnkeaoatnyqd/Build/Intermediates/G4EMA.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/G4EMA.build/Objects-normal/i386/G4EMA.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -objc,-all_load -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=5.1 /Users/macuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/G4EMA-djubtvaxtspjxbbolnkeaoatnyqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libMapView.a -lz -framework SystemConfiguration -lsqlite3 -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreLocation -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/macuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/G4EMA-djubtvaxtspjxbbolnkeaoatnyqd/Build/Intermediates/G4EMA.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/G4EMA.build/Objects-normal/i386/G4EMA_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/macuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/G4EMA-djubtvaxtspjxbbolnkeaoatnyqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/G4EMA.app/G4EMA

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RMTileImage", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libMapView.a(RMMapTiledLayerView.o)
"_RMTileDummy", referenced from:
  -[RMFractalTileProjection normaliseTile:] in   libMapView.a(RMFractalTileProjection.o)
"_RMTileKey", referenced from:
  +[RMTileCache tileHash:] in libMapView.a(RMTileCache.o)
  -[RMAbstractWebMapSource imageForTile:inCache:] in libMapView.a(RMAbstractWebMapSource.o)
  ___47-[RMAbstractWebMapSource imageForTile:inCache:]_block_invoke in libMapView.a(RMAbstractWebMapSource.o)
  ___47-[RMAbstractWebMapSource imageForTile:inCache:]_block_invoke108 in libMapView.a(RMAbstractWebMapSource.o)
  ___42-[RMCompositeSource imageForTile:inCache:]_block_invoke in libMapView.a(RMCompositeSource.o)
  ___42-[RMCompositeSource imageForTile:inCache:]_block_invoke_2 in libMapView.a(RMCompositeSource.o)
"_RMTileMake", referenced from:
  -[RMMapTiledLayerView drawLayer:inContext:] in libMapView.a(RMMapTiledLayerView.o)
  -[RMTileCache beginBackgroundCacheForTileSource:southWest:northEast:minZoom:maxZoom:] in libMapView.a(RMTileCache.o)
  ___85-[RMTileCache beginBackgroundCacheForTileSource:southWest:northEast:minZoom:maxZoom:]_block_invoke_2 in libMapView.a(RMTileCache.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am truly at a loss as to why this is happening, my Research on s/o has drawn a blank so any information or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Choose your target, look at the build phases tab and the link libraries section.  You may have to add the library with the RM* classes there.

Comment: thanks philip, the library is in there but it is red!

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  Undefined symbols for architecture i386 could mean that the library is not compiled to run on the simulator.  Have you tried to compile for a device and received same error?

Comment: I wasted so much time on trying to get it to work I gave up and went back to the older version of route me and it works fine